# UI form in Magento 2

Tags: php, magento2.2, ui-form

In the below code which path or which file name have to give in 7 th line instead of slide. Because i am creating Ui form  in backend

```
<field name="name">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Name</item>
            <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
            <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
            <item name="source" xsi:type="string">slide</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</field>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the module structure like Vendor/Module/Component - according to the  hierarchy you should place **component** in your item  name="source".In your case it would be the following:

```
<item name="source" xsi:type="string">homeslider</item>
```

Comment: I am new to magento . Would you don't mind please explain what is the component ? ...

Comment: Yourcompaname/Yourmodulename/(here any folder you made for you module is component ). If we talk about the cms module then , it will be Magento/Cms/Page ... in this case page is component.

Comment: Jai is a vendor name and HomeSlider is a module name. I have Controller, Model,etc,view,Ui,Setup, Block... Now can you tell me

Comment: then place homeslider in  your item name="source"

Answer (score 1):

You need to follow the core magento xml hierarchy root directory then go to vendor/magento/Module-name/

You can also refer to this url

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/ui_comp_guide/components/ui-form.html